# Why are Sonogashira reactions moisture sensitive?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, organometallic-compounds

Exemple, aryl halide + TMS-acetylene in NEt3 + Pd[PPh3]2Cl2 or Pd[PPh3]4:

The reaction does not form water at any time so its presence wouldn't shift the equilibrium. Neither TMS-acetylene or the aryl halide are subject to react with water. This would signify that the Palladium catalyst is moisture sensitive. Yet, Palladium can not be oxidized by water as oxidative addition of water isn't possible (OA of OH extremely rare) and beta hydrogen elimination to form Pd=OH seems impossible?

Hope someone will be able to enlighten me.

Comment: Quenching of the copper acetylide possibly

Comment: The addition of CuI as co-catalyst allows to lower the reaction temperature (often ambient instead of say $\pu{100 ^\circ{}C}$) and to use a mix of THF (for solubility) and aqueous ammonia as solvent, possibly passing a Cu acetylide.  See e.g. [2002ChemLett756](https://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/10.1246/cl.2002.756) and [2005BullChemSocJpn160](https://www.journal.csj.jp/doi/10.1246/bcsj.78.160). The conditions equally suit a carbonylation ([2003OrgLett3057](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ol035007a), a visual [abstract](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/abstracts/literature/605.shtm)).